# reformat date that is pulled from database table

Tags: date, smarty

I have a website which uses smarty templates.

I have a table in my db called `posts` that has various columns, one being "`date_added`". I managed to have that displayed on the posts by editing one of the **Smarty** templates for "`posts`" however, the date format is `YYYY-MM-D`D.

Is there any easy way for me to change this? Perhaps with jQuery?

Ideally, I want to only show the abbreviated `month`, with the day positioned next it. This is for a blog style post, but this isn't WordPress.

Right now the smartytemplate the shows the `date_added` reads like this:

```
{$posts[i].date_added|stripslashes|nl2br}
```

Where posts is the table and `date_added` is a column in that table.

An exact example can be seen here in the top right corner of each post.

http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/LightBright/

Does anyone have a good suggestion of how I can achieve the desired request?

Comment: Why not simple use `date_format` ? In Smarty 3 you can do it like this `{$posts[i].date_added|date_format:'M d'}`. If you use an older Smarty version, you can try this `{$posts[i].date_added|date_format:'%b %d'}` instead.

Comment: @sofl Thanks!!! How can I select your solution as the answer? This worked perfectly. This is the first time I used smarty, so I didn't know it could be written like that. `[i].date_added|date_format:'%b %d'}` is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a javascript solution, you can take a look at the incredible JS Library  MomentJS. It is very lightweight and does numerous date and time formats.

http://momentjs.com/

Just include the minified script file in your HTML .

For your exact case, you would use momentJS as such:
First create the momentJS date object:

```
var moment_date = moment(date_from_database, "YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Then to display the date as you want:

```
var date_string = moment_date.format("MMM DD");  // ex. = "Mar 03"
```

More documentation here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Then you can use your DOM manipulation library (JQuery for example) to place that string somewhere in your HTML

Good luck
- K